# case sensitive dir in cmd.exe

Tags: windows, cmd, dir, glob

I just experienced a search `dir *T.java` in a cmd.exe giving back `SortedArrayList.java` as well as `ReaderT.java` (my Test class filename structure). I can't infer a case sensitivity switch from the help output of `dir /?`. Is there still a way though?

*Addendum: I assume from the answers "Windows File System" refers to NTFS or FAT[32].*

For my purposes I got inspired from the answers to use `dir /b /s *T.class | grep T\.`  Which created a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814733/cmd-exe-s-dir-bare-format-no-heading-no-summary)

Comment: Shameless plug: possible duplicate of [Listing entries in a directory using grep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715387/listing-entries-in-a-directory-using-grep)

Comment: This question is specifically about directory listing Windows.  Is it really appropriate to label it as a duplicate of a Linux-related question?

Comment: @Paddy Exact duplicate? Certainly not. Possible duplicate, maybe. You even mention `grep` in your answer.

Comment: link is broken, please update it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a quick google-fu:

> 1.1  Introduction to Windows' File System
>
> In Windows, files are organized in directories (aka folders). The directories are organized in a hierarchical tree structure, starting from the root directory. A directory may contain sub-directories and files. The root directory is denoted as "\" (back-slash).Windows' file system is further organized in drive, identified by a drive letter followed by a colon (e.g., C:, D:, E:). Each drive has its own root directory, such as C:\, D:.
>   Windows' file system is NOT case-sensitive, a rose is a Rose, and is a ROSE.

So no, there is no "case-senstive" option when using DIR.
On the other hand, you can try to check case sensitivity on the side of the program which will be executing the file search.. In this case Java, as I presume. Just get all the files which match and then filter out the case-insensitive matches in Java.

Answer (score 3):

Not to my knowledge.  Windows file system is not case-sensitive, and until more recently you couldn't rely on your capitalisations to be preserved (okay so I'm thinking back a few versions of Windows now).  So, as a result, Microsoft's `dir` command completely ignores the fact that you might want case-sensitivity.

Instead, you should try piping the output through `grep` for Windows, which is part of the GnuWin32 project: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm

A complete list of packages is at: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html

Pretty useful stuff to have if you have a Linux background and are forced into doing anything remotely useful in Windows command shell.

So, long story short, you'd want to do something like:

```
dir /b | grep T\.java
```

Comment: Cygwin tools like `ls` are case-sensitive in FS handling too. And they can be called from `cmd` provided `cygwin\bin` is in `PATH`.

Comment: Sure... if you really think it's worth installing cygwin just for that.

Comment: Well, UNIX cmdline tools put `.bat` files to shame when it comes to automating any real-life tasks. So I really think it'll become not 'just for that' pretty soon.

Answer (score 3):

You can use find instead of grep if you don't want to install additional tools.

```
dir /b /s | find "T.class"
```

Comment: I also do this.  It works perfectly and is easy to incorporate into batch scripts.

Comment: It should be `dir /b /s | find "T.class"` (without `*` in the find argument)

Comment: this is the best solution. but I wonder you add the `/b` 

Comment: @FoadS.Farimani so you only get full paths. Otherwise you get file and directory information on separate lines. So you would still get a listing of files names, but you would not know what directory they were in

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using PowerShell, then you could also try

```
dir | Where-Object {$_.Name -clike "*T.java"}
```

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26432185/4999991))

please consider:

- `dir` and `ls` in PowerShell are aliases of `Get-ChildItem` command.
- `where` and `?` are also aliases of `Where-Object` command.

Answer (score -1):

Use `dir /L` to output in lower case.

Comment: This only concerns the output, not the files selected/matched by the pattern.

Comment: Correct.  It should have been clear that the OP wanted to list only files with a capital `T` immediately before a `.java` extension.