# How to do a case-sensitive file search with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, search, case-sensitive

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Filter CAPS*
```

finds **caps.txt**
I want to make sure it will only find
**CAPS.txt**  (or e.g.  **CAPS901918.whatever**)

I've tried find ways to pipe the Filter to an expression like:

```
{ $_.What_I_just_said_to_filter_on -like [A-Z] }
```

or suppress output after receiving results but I have found nothing.

Comment: Don't forget `-Recurse` if you want to look in subdirectories. `-Force` will grab hidden and system files. Also run this from an elevated prompt else you would could get lots of errors using `-Recurse`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try piping `Get-Childitem` to `Where-Object` like this:

```
Get-Childitem -Path C:\ | Where-Object {$_.what_you_want_to_filter -cmatch "REGEX"}
```

here it is with like syntax (thanks FLGMwt)

```
Get-Childitem -Path C:\ | Where-Object {$_.Name -clike "CAPS*"}
```

Comment: Note, `-match` takes a regex. Alternatively, if you prefer `like` syntax, `-clike` enforces case sensitivity.

Comment: Use `-cmatch` for case-sensitive match.

Answer (score 6):

The FileSystem provider's filter is not case sensitive, but you can  pipe it to:

```
Where{-NOT ($_.BaseName -cmatch "[a-z]")}
```

That will find files that do not contain lower case letters. If you match against upper case it will work for any file that has at least 1 capital letter, and can still include lower case.

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex option for this

```
| Where{ $_.BaseName -match "(?-i)^[A-Z]+") }
```

Or

```
| Where{ $_.BaseName -cmatch "^[A-Z]+"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a nice little powershell app I wrote for searching and outputting item's it found to a log file on your desktop if you're interested.

```
# Creates Log File
function Create-MyLog()
{
    Clear-Host
    New-Item -Path "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Desktop\" -Name "MyLogFile.txt" -ItemType file -Force
    Clear-Host
    Smart-Search
}

# Gather Search And Execute
function Smart-Search()
{   
    Clear-Host
    $LogFilePath = "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Desktop\"
    $TestInput = Read-Host 'What Would You Like To Search'
    $TestSearch = $TestInput + "*"
    $MyLogFile = ($LogFilePath + "MyLogFile.txt")
    Set-Location "C:\"
    $itemSum = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        Foreach($itemInst in $itemSum)
            {
                if(($itemInst.Name -clike $TestSearch) -eq $true)
                    {
                        $itemInst.FullName | Out-File -LiteralPath $MyLogFile -Append
                    }
                elseif($itemInst -eq $null)
                    {
                        Write-Host "Search Error On searchInst Is Null"
                    }
            }
        Search-Again
}

# Ask If User Wants To Search Again
function Search-Again()
{
    $userAnswer = Read-Host 'Would You Like To Search Again? y/n'
        switch($true)
            {
                ($userAnswer -eq "y"){Smart-Search};
                ($userAnswer -eq "n"){};
                default{Write-Host "Invalid Response"; Search-Again};
            }
}
Create-MyLog
```