# Case sensitivity in AWS cli move needed in powershell

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, command-line-interface, case-sensitive

I am new to PowerShell, I want move files using using AWS CLI:

```
aws s3 mv s3://bucket_nm/src_path/ s3://bucket_nm/tgt_path/archive/ --recursive --exclude * --include Test_*
```

The issue is it is moving `test*`, `Test*`. The same command in Linux moves only `Test*`, how do I achieve the same results in PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a PowerShell issue. Windows in general is not case sensitive but design, where we all know *Nix is case sensitive by design.

So, you doing this in PowerShell, is going to move anything that matches the wildcard, ignoring case, by design.

You can use PowerShell and RegEx to specify case sensitivity. ***Though I've never tried to do that with AWS CLI***, as I only use AWS PowerShell, since PowerShell is what I use everywhere else, even on my OSX and Linux clients these days.

As discussed in this Q&A:
[How to do a case-sensitive file search with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26432076/how-to-do-a-case-sensitive-file-search-with-powershell)

```
Get-Childitem -Path C:\ | Where-Object {$_.what_you_want_to_filter -match "REGEX"}

Get-Childitem -Path C:\ | Where-Object {$_.Name -clike "CAPS*"}
```

You could use the above cmdlet, then pipe that to the Move-Item cmdlet, or just use the Move-Item cmdlet directly.

***Update for the OP***

As for...

> But not able to figure out how can I integrate powershell
>   case-sensitive tools with aws cli move.

What you are showing is in the AWS CLI you are using a normal comparison operation, you can use comparison operator as well. Example

```
'Test*' -eq 'Test*'
True
'test*' -ceq 'Test*'
False
```

Are you saying, you've tried those, and the did not get you what you were after?

[PowerShell -eq, -ceq and -ieq Comparison Operators](https://techibee.com/powershell/understanding-windows-powershell-eq-ceq-and-ieq-operators/2652)

[Comparison Operators](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-compare.html)

Or change your code to do this...

```
'test*','Test*' | select-string -pattern 'Test*'
test*
Test*


'test*','Test*' | select-string -pattern 'Test*' -CaseSensitive
Test*
```

I messed with this a bit more on my local drive, I have no S3 things and as stated don't use AWS CLI in any of my AWS use cases.

Try this, if you are only of course looking for the first char to capitalized.

```
Clear-Host
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp\*Test*').FullName

<#
D:\Temp\BusinessTest.pptx
D:\Temp\BusinessTest.pptx - Shortcut.lnk
D:\Temp\Test.clixml
D:\Temp\test.csv
D:\Temp\test.docx
D:\Temp\test.zip
D:\Temp\TestD&DScript.gif
#>

Clear-Host
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp\*Test*' | 
Where-Object {$_.Name -cmatch '^[A-Z].*'} 

<#
    Directory: D:\Temp


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        7/27/2018  12:38 PM          33520 BusinessTest.pptx
-a----         8/4/2018  11:44 PM           1084 BusinessTest.pptx - Shortcut.lnk
-a----        10/2/2018   5:26 PM            202 Test.clixml
-a----        8/24/2018   7:37 PM         439363 TestD&DScript.gif
#>
```

So, maybe...

```
${v_file_exst_chk} = (aws s3 ls s3://${v_full_src_path}) | 
Where-Object {$_.Name -cmatch '^[A-Z].*'}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However I want to move multiple files at once using aws move, dont want and external loop to fire one move for each file.  
I am using aws ls like below to achieve case sensitvity-  

`${v_file_exst_chk}=(aws s3 ls s3://${v_full_src_path}| Select-String -Pattern ${v_file_name_mask_rplc_str} -CaseSensitive|Measure-Object).Count`  But not able to figure out how can I integrate powershell case-sensitive tools with aws cli move.