# How to find ls only files with uppercases in name?

Tags: regex, powershell, match, uppercase

I want to filter only files and folders with name start with `2[A-Z]` (uppercase only):

```
ls -recurse | Where-Object {$_.name -match '2[A-Z]'}
```

But it still returns lowercase files. Reading the [`-match` parameter of `Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.3#-match) I don't see a way to fix this.

Comment: As an aside: Your doc link describes the `-Match` _parameter_ of the `Where-Object` cmdlet, which, when using [simplified syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Simplified_Syntax), refers to the [`-match` _operator_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch), which exists independently of the cmdlet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do a case-sensitive file search with PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26432076/how-to-do-a-case-sensitive-file-search-with-powershell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PowerShell's comparison operators are case-*insensitive*** by default, but they have **[`c`-prefixed variants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#common-features)** that are **case-*sensitive***, namely **`-cmatch`** in the case of the [`-match` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch):

```bash
gci -recurse | Where-Object { $_.Name -cmatch '^2[A-Z]' }
```

- `gci` is used as the PowerShell-idiomatic alternative to the Windows-only `ls` alias for [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem).

  - See the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74591072/45375) for more information on why aliases named for commands or utilities of a different shell or platform are best avoided.
- [Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) assertion `^` is used to ensure that the pattern only matches at the *start* of file names.

---

Alternatively, use **[simplified syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Simplified_Syntax)**:

```bash
gci -recurse | Where-Object Name -cmatch '^2[A-Z]'
```

Comment: @Ooker, please see my update, also re simplified syntax.